# NoSuchSessionException in java selenium cucumber framework while running second test case

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, cucumber

Here is the issue below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: invalid session id
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-3', revision: '*****'
System info: host: '*****', ip: '******', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.130, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: C:\Windows\TEMP\scoped_dir1...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60550}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: **********
```

Hey guys, I am trying to run batch execution of cucumber framework. But i was not able to do that. I am able to run a single feature file but not two. In the second run of the feature file after the first test has passed, the browser opens and enters the url, but no further action takes place. Username field is not getting filled. Only the first case is passing and second is failing. Please let me know the fix of the issue. Right now i am using latest selenium and chrome i.e  os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_231', Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver, Chrome latest - v.80. I hope someone can resolve my issue.